# Calculus Tangent Line Problem (Determine the $x$ coordinates)

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble solving this tangent line problem for my calculus class.

Q. Consider the tangent line to the graph of $f(x) = x^4 - 11x^2 + 28$ at the point where $x = 1$. Determine the $x$-coordinate(s) where the tangent line intersects the graph.

Now this is what I've done so far.

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= 4x^3 - 22x\\
f'(1) &= 4(1)^3 - 22(1)\\
      &= 4 - 22\\
    m &= -18\\
f(1) &= (1)^4 - 11(1)^2 + 28\\
     &= 1 - 11 + 28\\
     &= 18\\
y - y_1 &= m(x - x_1)\\
y - 18  &= -18(x - 1)\\
y &= -18x + 36
\end{align*}
Now how can I get an answer using what I have so far?
Also if I were to graph this, what would it look like?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good so far! Call the "y" for the tangent line g(x) or something. Now how do you find the intersection points of g(x) and f(x)?

Comment: f(x)=-18x+36 $$x^4-11x^2+28=-18x+36\\x^4-11x^2+28+18x-36=0\\$$one of roots is x=1 and other is x=-4 ,(-4,108) is intersects of tangent line and graph

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If the graph of $y=-18x+36$ mets that one of $f(x)=x^4-11x^2+28$ at a point $(x,y)$ then their $y$-coordinates must be equal, i.e.
$$x^4-11x^2+28=-18x+36\iff x^4-11x^2+18x-8=0$$

Comment: so I get (x-1)^2(x^2+2x-8) therefore x = -4, 1, 2

Comment: You know that the line is tangent to the curve at $(1,18)$ so we take the other two values: $x=-4$ and $x=2$.